# How to delete related fields using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an object like this :

```
public class MyObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ExternalNumber { get; set; }


    public virtual InternalProperties InProperties { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AdditionalPrice> PriceHistory{ get; set; }
}
```

And InternalProperties class :

```
public class InternalProperties
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  Field1{get; set;}
}
```

And PriceHistory :

```
public class AdditionalPrice
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
}
```

And my context look like this :

```
public class myContext : DbContext
{
        static myContext ()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<myContext >(null);
        }

        public myContext ()
            : base("myCtx")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<MyObject> Objects{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
           modelBuilder.Entity<myObject>().HasOptional(m => m.InProperties );
           modelBuilder.Entity<myObject>().HasMany(m => m.PriceHistory);
        }

}
```

Finally I'm trying to delete myObjects like this :

```
            using (var _sdb = new MyContext())
            {
                _sdb.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                var myList = _sdb.Objects.Where(m => m.Id > 5).OrderBy(c => c.Id).ToList();
                foreach(var obj in myList)
                {
                 _sdb.Objects.Remove(obj)
                }

            }
_sdb.SaveChanges();
```

I'm getting this exception at SaveChanges():

> {"An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign
>   key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property
>   will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the
>   source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be
>   made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types.
>   See the InnerException for details."}

And Inner Exception says :

> {"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   \"FK_dbo.AdditionalPrice_dbo.MyObject_MyObject_Id\". The conflict
>   occurred in database \"myobject\", table \"dbo.AdditionalPrice\",
>   column 'myObject_Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

The exceptions are pretty explanatory but I don't know how to delete these objects safely. I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the message is clear, there's foreign key, and you should delete foreign records first

Comment: @LeiYang Yes I get that too, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @LeiYang I can't reach and delete that Price history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need something like this:

```
var pricesToBeDeleted = _sdb.AdditionalPrices.Where(ap=>ap.MyObjectId == obj.Id);
_sdb.AdditionalPrices.Remove(pricesToBeDeleted);
_sdb.Objects.Remove(obj)
```

The `AdditionalPrices` would be of type `DbSet<AdditionalPrice>`. You should add the following line in your `myContext` class:

```
public DbSet<AdditionalPrice> Objects{ get; set; }
```

Regarding the `AdditionalPrice` class, I don't see the foreign key to `MyObject`. I think that you miss something there. I mean that you might have something like the following:

```
public class AdditionalPrice
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
    public int MyObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

where `MyObjectId` is the foreign key. If the name `MyObjectId` isn't the same with the corresponding column name you should change, in order they match one another.

Comment: As you can see my context doesn't have AdditionalPrices. Should I add that into context first?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was writing a few seconds before :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the AdditionalPrice class doesn't have a foreign key. Is it still safe to delete using Id?

Comment: @jason You are welcome. If I am not wrong the `Id` is the primary key of the record, not the foreign key to the `MyObject` table. That being said I think that this is not correct. Furthermore, since the error message you get refers to a foreign key and the `AdditionPrice` represents  a record of the corresponding table shouldn't we have there a property like `MyObjectId`, which would have been the foreign key?